# Is there a way to determine the pull-down resistance of a FPGA pin?

Tags: fpga, measurement

I have an FPGA and don't have access to the code used to program it. The data sheet specifies that you can configure pull-down resistors that vary from 50-100 ohms.

Can you measure the value of a pull-down resistor inside an FPGA? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probe the pin directly and inject a current.  Plot the V vs. I curve of the pin to determine it's true nature (it's likely just a transistor wired as diode - so a current sink).  Start with a few mA and ramp up to what you think is reasonable without over-volting the part.